# Search in Mysql Json Collection data

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, json, mysql-5.7

I've a problem and I wish get your help to solve it.

Actually, I've an items Mysql table. And I have a characteristics column which is json datatype.

This is an example to explain what I'm saying.

- The table structure

```
CREATE TABLE item ( 
                    `id`             INT(11)     NOT NULL, 
                    `name`           VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
                    `characteristic` JSON        NOT NULL 
                   )   
       ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

- The table data

```
INSERT INTO `item` (`id`, `name`, `characteristic`) VALUES
(3, 'Mouse', '[{\"name\": \"length\", \"value\": 6}, 
               {\"name\": \"width\" , \"value\": 3}, 
               {\"name\": \"height\", \"value\": 2}]'),
(4, 'Car'  , '[{\"name\": \"length\", \"value\":11}, 
               {\"name\": \"width\" , \"value\": 7}, 
               {\"name\": \"height\", \"value\": 8}]');
```

So, I need to get all items which have the characteristic length > 10.

Many thanks in advance for your suggestions and help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JSON_EXTRACT()` function along with `Recursive CTE` such as

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS 
(
  SELECT 1 AS n
  UNION ALL
  SELECT n + 1 AS value
    FROM cte
   WHERE cte.n < (SELECT MAX(JSON_LENGTH(`characteristic`)) FROM `item` )
)
SELECT i.*
  FROM cte
  JOIN `item` AS i     
 WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(`characteristic`,CONCAT('$[',n-1,'].value')) > 10
   AND JSON_EXTRACT(`characteristic`,CONCAT('$[',n-1,'].name')) = "length"
```

Considering your DB version is `5.7`, you can use the following iteration logic

```
SELECT  i.*
  FROM `item` AS i
  JOIN (SELECT @i := @i + 1 AS n
          FROM `item` AS i
          JOIN (SELECT @i := -1) AS iter
          LEFT JOIN  information_schema.tables AS t
            ON @i < JSON_LENGTH(`characteristic`) - 1) AS t
 WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(`characteristic`,CONCAT('$[',n,'].value')) > 10
   AND JSON_EXTRACT(`characteristic`,CONCAT('$[',n,'].name')) = "length"
```

in this case the index of the key `"name"` equals to `"length"` is determined within the array, and then this index is used to check out whether the `"value"` is greater than `10`.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f6b95e5d4bd75a4bdd3e5d51db3e74b5)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you. 
I forgot to mention that I've a version 5.7 of MySql. Sorry about that.
So unfortunately it doesn't work with MySql version 5.7. Is there any way to rewrite this query for MySql 5.7?
Thanks